# When superclass holds pointer to X, and subclass to Y : X

Tags: c++, inheritance

I can't think of a better title... please edit if you can!

```
class AbstractGUIBase
{
...
};
class GUIConcrete : public AbstractGUIBase
{
...
};

class AbstractApplicationBase
{
 AbstractGUIBase *mGUI;
};

class MyApplication : public AbstractApplicationBase
{
 GUIConcrete *mGUI;
};
```

This is basically the setup I have... an application base-class provides common functionality including a reference to a GUI base-class instance `mGUI`. `mGUI` is only ever instantiated in `MyApplication` or other concrete sub-classes.

I don't want to re-declare `mGUI` in both classes because I end up doing something like `super::mGUI = mGUI = new ConcreteGUI()`. But I also don't want to have to cast `mGUI` every time it's used in `MyApplication`.

Is there a normal patter here? I was thinking you could template `AbstractApplicationBase` on the GUI class type but I don't especially like template programming.

I'm using MSVC++2008 so no fancy modern stuff is available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll try to strip away the details of your model and focus on the following abstract design:

```
                struct A                    struct DA : A 
                {                           {
                };                          };

//==============================================================================

                struct B                    struct DB : B 
                {                           { 
                    A* p;                       DA* pD; // Avoid this
                };                          };
```

Now what you are trying to do is to avoid adding an *extra* member variable to `DB`, and be able to treat the pointer `p` inherited from `B` as if it were of type `DA*`.

You can structure classes `B` and `DB` this way:

```
struct B
{
private:
    A* p;
public:
    B(A* _p) : p(_p) { }
    A* get_p() { return p; }
}

struct DB : B
{
public:
    B(DA* _p) : B(_p) { }
    DA* get_p() { return static_cast<DA*>(A::get_p()); }
}
```

Superclass `B` will hold a pointer of type `A*`. This pointer is set at construction time. If the constructor is invoked while creating an instance of `DB`, a pointer to an object of type `DA` will be stored. `DB` provides a function `get_p()` that hides `B`'s version of `get_p()` and returns a (properly casted) pointer of type `DA*`.

Due to this design, the `static_cast<>` in `DB::get_p()` is guaranteed to be safe (unless you use virtual inheritance, in which case you should use the less efficient `dynamic_cast<>`).

Internal operations of `B` would access the pointer `p` directly. Clients of `B` would retrieve it through a call to `B::get_p()`. Inside of `DB`, and for clients of `DB` as well, you would access the object pointed to by `p` by retrieving the pointer through function `B::get_p()`, rather than directly dereferencing `p`.

Comment: Shouldn't `B(DA* _p) : p(_p) { }` be `DB(DA* _p) : B(_p) { }
` instead?

Comment: So basically every time in DA I'd need access to DB*, extra function call invoking a static/dynamic cast is needed. Is there a way to do this, avoiding the cast? Maybe if we declare a union of A* and DA* for p, instead of just A*?

Comment: @gt6989b: If you use a `static_cast<>`, it's very likely that the compiler will inline that call, resulting in no overhead. If a `dynamic_cast<>` is used then yes, this will affect performance. I would not go for a `union`, because you would have to mention `DA` inside of `B`, and `B` is likely to be part of a framework that should not know anything about `DA`.

Comment: So basically, I'm being a bit idealistic in my quest for a clean, non-casted solution? Well-written answer by the way.

Comment: @John: Probably yes. I believe in this case the best you can do is indeed to minimize the number of places where the downcast is performed, by confining it into one function that you would invoke instead of accessing the pointer directly. Alternatives exist, for instance not storing the pointer at all in the base class and storing it only in the derived class, but I don't know how much control you have over the base class (I assume not much, since it seems to belong to a GUI framework).

Comment: @John: The alternative is to make `B::get_p()` abstract and let `B`'s functions invoke `B::get_p()` instead of accessing `p`. `DB` would then override `get_p()` and return `p`, so the base class can access it as well.